# sed variation in MacOSX with space and newline

Tags: regex, linux, macos, sed

Need to replace a comma followed by space with a newline

On LINUX I see people posting examples such as

```
sed 's/,\s/\n/g' textfile
```

Whereas in MacOSX this doesn't work but the following does

```
sed 's/, /\
/g' testfile
```

The  space as in real space and the newline character is an actual backslash with a newline 'entered'

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: OSX uses a BSD version of `sed`. Most linux distributions (if not all of them) use the GNU version of `sed`. They have slightly different behaviours. You can try using the `-E` flag and seeing if that works. Alternatively using `[[:space:]]` for `\s` should work but I'm not sure about an alternative to `\n` in the replacement.

Comment: Aah, okay. So is this change documented anywhere ?
This means scripting will have to cater for this as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On OSX you can do:

```
sed -i.bak 's/, /\'$'\n''/g' file
```

Or this:

```
sed -i.bak $'s/, /\\\n/g' file
```

As per `man bash`:

```
 Words  of  the  form  $'string'  are  treated specially.  The word expands to string, 
 with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. 
 Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
          \a     alert (bell)
          \b     backspace
          \e     an escape character
          \f     form feed
          \n     new line
          \r     carriage return
          \t     horizontal tab
          \v     vertical tab
          \\     backslash
          \'     single quote
          \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn
                 (one to three digits)
          \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH
                 (one or two hex digits)
          \cx    a control-x character
```

Comment: can you please explain this -> '$'\n''

Comment: Added some explanation of use of `$'string` in question.